# Get canvas context with webdriverio

Tags: javascript, canvas, webdriver-io

I am testing an html canvas with webdriverio and I need to test the color of a pixel on the canvas.

```
client.element('#canvas-id');
    }).then(function (ele) {
        var ctx = ele.getContext('2d');
        var canvasColor = ctx.getImageData(50, 10, 1, 1).data;
        //assert black at center of line
        assert.equal(canvasColor[0], 255);
        assert.equal(canvasColor[1], 255);
        assert.equal(canvasColor[2], 255);
    });
```

So instead of the JSON object returned by client.element, I need to get the actual html element so the getContext is available.  Is this possible to do with the webdriverio framework?

Answer (score 1):

your `ele` is a `WebElement`, which is a sort of representation of the actual element in your browser. It does not have a `getImageData` method, 
`WebElement` has no special functionality to interact with a `canvas`.

**So you need to [execute](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html) your request on the client side:**

```
//...
}).then(function (ele) {
    client.execute(function(element) 
    { 
      // this code gets executed on the client
      return element.getContext('2d').getImageData(50, 10, 1, 1).data;
    }, ele).then(function(canvasColor)
    {
      //assert black at center of line
      assert.equal(canvasColor[0], 255);
      assert.equal(canvasColor[1], 255);
      assert.equal(canvasColor[2], 255);
    });
});
```

(I didn't test the code, please let us know if it works)